# iOS 11 tableView with Style Grouped makes large title become invalid

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

I gave my tableViewController a large title Style programmatically:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and in storyboard, I made tableView "Static Cell" content, and "Grouped" Style in Attributes inspector:

[image]

But largeTitle didn't work when I ran the app, if tableView style is "Plain", it works. How can I fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Also, according to your screenshot, you **did not** enable large titles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your case, but for me using `tableView.bounces = false` prevented the large-title from working. Removing this line did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why this occurs.  Quite possibly a bug.  But here is a work around.  In Document Outline.  Select your Navigation Controller Scene -> Navigation Bar then select Prefer Large Titles (at the top) in Attribute Inspector like so:

[image]

After making this change, if you want other view controllers to have regular / plain titles, simply add this to viewDidLoad() on that particular V.C.

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Comment: It works，thank you ！
But if I make the tableView style "Plain" , it doesn't need to select "Prefers Large Titles" checkbox .

Comment: If you take a look at the answer to this post, it appears that grouping TableViews definitely has a few bugs that need to be worked out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510406/swift-uitableviewcontroller-modify-margin-between-uitableview-and-view-contro

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`. I putted it in `ViewDidload` and it's works properly 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you , but I did put that line in viewDidLoad . It only works when the tableView style is "Plain" . I tried the above solution , and it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove title from your storyboard
2. In your UIViewController over viewDidLoad function:

   ```swift
   navigationItem.title = "Search title"
   navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
   ```