# Swift: UITableViewController - modify margin between UITableView and View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableViewController in my app. It works well but default UITableViewController is adding some spacing between UITableView embedded inside it and main View of UITableViewController. Look at below image. How can I remove/modify this spacing form storyboard or from code?

[image]

In blue is my custom row. The spacing is between this blue tableView row and green navigation bar.

Comment: uncheck Adjust Scroll View insets in storyboard

Comment: You are sure you are using UITableViewController?  Not UIViewController subclassing UITableViewController?

Comment: ok, I understand you @Sandeep

Comment: @ReinierMelian That is good. Sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: Don't worry man!, @Sandeep see you, best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in ViewDidLoad helped me:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude))
```

It is also possible to remove this by implementing delegate methods

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

      return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

But in the second approach it automatically removes all spacing also between TableView sections.

I have also heard that this problems occurs for Grouped style of UITableView.